# sent 500 lend tokens to my ETH crypto wallet in error

Tags: tokens

Hi there I hope you can help. I have mistakenly sent 500 Aave (Lend) tokens to my ETH wallet address on crypto.com. Please can you advise what I can do to get back into my orginal wallet?
Below is the transaction on etherscan:
https://etherscan.io/token/0x80fb784b7ed66730e8b1dbd9820afd29931aab03?a=0xb30b3304d979a06f02fee7d304b109dafd5ba9d7

Regards
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

The transaction has already been processed and it's final. If the wallet doesn't support the token natively, you can simply contact the crypto.com customer support to ask what could be done about it.

The assets are not gone, it's just a matter of what the wallet supports and how nice their customer support is.